# How does Isaiah's Idiom "Like-a Drop From-a Bucket" (כְּמַ֣ר מִדְּלִ֔י) symbolize Nations (גּוֹיִם֙)?

Tags: isaiah, hebrew-bible, symbolism

We read a poetic simile from the prophet Yeshayahu "Ke-Mar Mi-Deliy" in **Isaiah 40:15** [MT] :

> "Behold the nations are like a drop from a bucket" (הֵ֚ן גּוֹיִם֙ כְּמַ֣ר מִדְּלִ֔י).

**How does Isaiah's Idiom "Like-a Drop From-a Bucket" (כְּמַ֣ר מִדְּלִ֔י) symbolize Nations (גּוֹיִם֙)?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The passage in Isa 40:9-31 is a wonderful eulogy about the greatness of God.  It uses a series of similes to show how great God is:

- V12 - measures all the waters (= seas) in the hollow if His hand
- V12 - measures the heavens with the span of His hand
- V12 - hold all the dust of earth in a basket
- V12 - can weigh all the mountains in a scale
- V13 - greater than all wisdom - no one can teach Him anything
- V15 - all the nations are but a drop in the bucket to Him
- V15 - the nations are but a speck of dust on God's scales
- V15 - the islands are like fine dust to Him
- V16 - all Lebanon's wood would not be enough for God's needs
- V16 - all the animals in the world would not be enough for God's sacrifice needs
- V17 - all the nations are as nothing to Him

... and so forth.  Thus, "the nations are like a drop in a bucket" is absolutely consistent with the extended hyperbole in this passage - God is truly great and awesome (Deut 10:17, Ps 68:35, 89:7, Dan 9:4, Neh 1:5, etc).  There is none like Him.

Matthew Henry observes for this passage:

> 40:12-17 All created beings shrink to nothing in comparison with the
> Creator. When the Lord, by his Spirit, made the world, none directed
> his Spirit, or gave advice what to do, or how to do it. The nations,
> in comparison of him, are as a drop which remains in the bucket,
> compared with the vast ocean; or as the small dust in the balance,
> which does not turn it, compared with all the earth.